# Full calendar date time picker issue Jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using datetimepicker plugin to show the mini calendar via custom button in fullcalendar, I am using this code to show it

```
 customButtons: {
        datePickerButton: {
            themeIcon:'circle-triangle-s',
            click: function () {


                var $btnCustom = $('.fc-datePickerButton-button'); // name of custom  button in the generated code
                $btnCustom.after('<input type="hidden" id="hiddenDate" class="datepicker"/>');

                $("#hiddenDate").datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",

                    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', dateText);
                    },
                });

                var $btnDatepicker = $(".ui-datepicker-trigger"); // name of the generated datepicker UI 
                //Below are required for manipulating dynamically created datepicker on custom button click
                $("#hiddenDate").show().focus().hide();
                $btnDatepicker.trigger("click"); //dynamically generated button for datepicker when clicked on input textbox
                $btnDatepicker.hide();
                $btnDatepicker.remove();
                $("input.datepicker").not(":first").remove();//dynamically appended every time on custom button click

            }
        }
    }
```

and it works fine , but now i need an input field where i can show the current date , for the moment I only have the custom button and when I click it opens the mini calendar, this is how it should look like

[Example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAXvB.png)

Comment: you just want an input tag in which you can display current date or the date selected.Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @ShubhamSharma i am sorry for the late response , i was busy

Answer (score 0):

you can use onselect event of datepicker

HTML

```
<input name="dtpicker" class="datepicker form-control" id="datepicker1">
<br>
<input id="datepickervalue">
```

JS

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("#datepickervalue").val(dateText);
  }
});
```

fiddle for reference

```
https://jsfiddle.net/L5ok81h8/1/
```

Comment: I am talking for full calendar ,  sobi need to import this into calendar header , i already made a custom button that shows the jquerry mini calendar and i need this input method aswell to work with it